# Trouble waking MacBook Pro from sleep with Dell WD22TB4 dock

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, dock

I am using a MacBook Pro (model A1708) with a Dell WD22TB4 dock connected to 2 external monitors, an internet connection (RJ-45), and other peripherals. Typically, the laptop lid is closed, and I am satisfied with this setup. However, sometimes I face inconvenience. When my MacBook is in sleep mode, I need to lift the laptop lid, unplug and re-plug the dock Thunderbolt cable to wake it up, and only then do the two external monitors, internet connection, and other peripherals come back to life.
If the laptop is shut down, I should lift the lid and enter the password.

Interestingly, before I started using the Dell WD22TB4 dock, I used a different dock, the Dell WD19S (without Thunderbolt). Then, to wake up my MacBook from sleep, I just needed to press any random key on my external keyboard (connected to the dock via cable), and the display would light up, showing the login screen immediately. So the Dell WD19S worked almost perfectly for me.

With this in mind, I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to configure the Dell WD22TB4 dock to have the same
   wake-up experience as with the Dell WD19S, where the wake-up process
   worked instantly, without needing to re-connect the cable between
   the dock and MacBook?
2. Despite Dell stating on their website that the power button on the
   dock does not work with MacBook
   (https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124312/dell-thunderbolt-dock-wd19tb-and-apple-usb-c-hosts),
   have any enthusiasts found any workaround solutions that would allow turn
   on a MacBook by pressing the power button on the dock or at least
   wake it up from sleep using this button?

I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions to these issues.

[image: Dock/Mac setup]

Comment: Just to be clear, Dell *explicitly* states that this device isn’t compatible with Macs, but you still believe there’s a workaround?

Comment: That's it. Workarounds are called workarounds cause they aim to achieve goals/properties/etc that were initially unforeseen. Honestly, I don't have much hope of finding a solution. However, if it does happen, these questions were not in vain.